# $.ajax 400 Bad Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

The goal is to send an object via ajax to another server, which I've set up for CORS, here's the `$.ajax` snippet:

```
$.ajax "#{config.url_root}/register",
  type: "POST"
  data: model.attributes
  dataType: "json"
  success: (data, text, xhr) -> console.log data, text, xhr
  error: (xhr, text, error) -> console.log text, error
```

correctly `POSTS` the data, but with a `contentType` of `application/x-www-urlencoded; charset utf-8`; When I explicity set the value of `contentType` to "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, it executes with a request method of`OPTIONS`?! and fails to deliver the data (`404 Not Found`)

[image]

Comment: The options verb is normal when it comes to CORS, do you have access to the server logs? If so, does it ever make it to the get?

Comment: this route is a `POST` only route, would it help if i made a `GET` equivalent and checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the XMLHttpRequest's `Content-Type` to `application/json` you're turning a *simple* cross-domain request into a **non-simple** cross-domain request ([read more about CORS here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)) which means that your browser must send an preflight (`OPTIONS`) request prior to your intended request. This is done to verify with the server that the client from a different origin is allowed to make said request.

The only "simple" headers you can set are: `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, `Last-Event-ID`, and `Content-Type` (if it is set to one of: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`).